How to copy the value from one "column" to another in Bash?
I have a file with lines:
username="user1" email="vova.tupkin@msn.com"

I need to take the username from the email address and replace the username value with it,
so the end result will be:
username="vova.tupkin" email="vova.tupkin@msn.com"

I was thinking in this direction:
#!/bin/bash

while read LINE; do

FUN=$(awk -F "\"" '{ print $2}')
RUN=$(awk -F "\"" '{print $4}' | awk -F "@" '{print $1}')


sed 's/\$FUN/\$RUN/g'

done < test.file


awk is perfectly capable of dealing with all lines of an input file without needing the shell for it, see: Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice? (not that I'd do this particular task with awk, but the same applies to sed too)

A single sed should sort this out. Pick out the email address and substitute it back into the username part:
echo 'username="user1" email="vova.tupkin@msn.com"' |
    sed -E 's/(username=")[^"]*(" email="([^@]*)@.*")/\1\3\2/'

The (...) define numbered pattern match groups that can be used as \1, \2, etc.
Output
username="vova.tupkin" email="vova.tupkin@msn.com"


Similar, but don't care about the original username label at all: sed -e 's/^.*email="\([^@]*\)@\([^"]*\)"/username="\1" email="\1@\2"/' file

sed -E 's/".*(".*"(.*)@)/"\2\1/' would do.

Here is the solution using any awk:
awk -F\" 'BEGIN{OFS=FS} {split($4,a,"@");$2=a[1]}1' <input file> > <output file>

